# django error when connecting with odoo xmlrpc

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, odoo, xmlrpclib

I can not connect with odoo in any way, this is what I am doing:

**view.py**

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class ProxiedTransport(Transport):

    def set_proxy(self, host, port=None, headers=None):
        self.proxy = host, port
        self.proxy_headers = headers

    def make_connection(self, host):
        connection = http.client.HTTPConnection(*self.proxy)
        connection.set_tunnel(host, headers=self.proxy_headers)
        self._connection = host, connection
        return connection

class ResUser(ViewSet):
    url = 'http://localhost'
    db = 'odoo8'
    username = 'admin'
    password = 'admin'

    def list(self,request,format=None):
        p = ProxiedTransport()
        p.set_proxy('proxy.server',8080)
        common = ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(self.url),p)
        uid = common.authenticate(self.db,self.username,self.password,{})

        return Response({})
```

But he throws me an error:

```
Request Method:     GET 
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/odoo-api/res/
Django Version:     2.1 
Exception Type:     gaierror 
Exception Value:    [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in getaddrinfo, line 745
```

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Do you change the default port of odoo server?

Comment: Which odoo version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

In **url** variable you need to add port number along with column sign for more information please check below example in python.

https://freeweblearns.blogspot.com/2018/11/how-to-use-xmlrpc-using-python-for-new.html